# Emitted Values Being Sent as One String Instead of Individual Values

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, mongoose

In my Angular app I'm returning results via an API call, and allowing users to filter those results through a series of checkbox selections. Right now I'm running into an issue where, while results are returned as expected when one value is sent for a certain filter, when multiple values are selected (like filtering by more than one zipcode, for instance) I get zero results printed to the view. No errors, just no results.

After scratching my head for a while, using Chrome devtools network tab, I finally determined that the problem is that rather than wrapping each item in quotes in the payload - like this: "90001", "90002", what's being sent is this: "90001, 90002". In other words, quotes are wrapped around as if it were one value, not two.

This is the code, where I'm using a "join" to put together the values that are selected:

```
this.sendZipcode.emit(this.zipcodeFilters.text = arr.length === 0 ? undefined : arr.join(','));
```

I'm not sure how I can adjust the way this "join" is constructed, or find some other solution instead of "join", in order to have each item wrapped in quotes, rather than wrapped like one long string.

FYI, this is what I see in the network tab of Chrome devtools after selecting two zipcodes. As I explained, it's wrapped like one string, rather than as two values:

```
addresses.zipCode: {$in: ["90001, 90002"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.join` will return a string.  So you are converting your array to a single string which is being sent as a string.  You want to send an array.  Simply remove the `join` call and return `arr` directly.

String: "value, value"

Array: "value", "value"

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG. I will give that a try.

Comment: So, send something like this?
this.sendZipcode.emit(this.zipcodeFilters.text = arr.length === 0 ? undefined : arr);